# Filter a list in list and preserve structure

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have this list

```
const foo = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: [ {id: 1, a: null}, {id: 2, a: 224}, {id: 3, a: 345}, ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bar: [ {id: 4, a: 763}, {id: 5, a: null}, {id: 3, a: 111}, ]
  }
]
```

How to I filter the list, that all `a: null` are removed, but the structure of the list remains the same?

I tried

```
foo.map(elem => elem.bar.filter(bar => bar.a !== null))
```

but that gives me.

```
foo = [
    [{id: 2, a: 224}, {id: 3, a: 345}, ],
    [ {id: 4, a: 763}, {id: 3, a: 111}, ]
]
```

I want the output to be

```
foo = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: [ {id: 2, a: 224}, {id: 3, a: 345}, ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bar: [ {id: 4, a: 763}, {id: 3, a: 111}, ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add the expected output. Do you want to filter` `bar` property or whole array.

Comment: @MaheerAli added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are okay with mutating the array, you could update `bar` with the filtered objects:

```js
const foo = [{id:1,bar:[{id:1,a:null},{id:2,a:224},{id:3,a:345},]},{id:2,bar:[{id:4,a:763},{id:5,a:null},{id:3,a:111},]}]

foo.forEach(o => o.bar = o.bar.filter(obj => obj.a !== null))

console.log(foo)
```

If you want a new array, then you could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const foo = [{id:1,bar:[{id:1,a:null},{id:2,a:224},{id:3,a:345},]},{id:2,bar:[{id:4,a:763},{id:5,a:null},{id:3,a:111},]}]

const newArray = foo.map(o => ({ ...o, bar: o.bar.filter(obj => obj.a !== null) }))

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are actually only filtering the inner array, then you want to use a `map` for the outer array.

```js
const original = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: [ {id: 1, a: null}, {id: 2, a: 224}, {id: 3, a: 345}, ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bar: [ {id: 4, a: 763}, {id: 5, a: null}, {id: 3, a: 111}, ]
  }
]

const result = original.map(elem => ({...elem, bar: elem.bar.filter(bar => bar.a !== null)}));

console.log(`result: ${JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}`);


// Note: original array unchanged
console.log(`original (unchanged): ${JSON.stringify(original, null, 2)}`);
```

Comment: There is no point in using `map` if you're mutating the original array

Comment: `elem.bar = elem.bar.filter...` mutates objects in `foo`. This could be done with just `foo.forEach(o => o.bar = ...` This all doesn't matter when you are reassigning `foo`

Comment: I understand that it doesn't mutate the original array, but generally mutating the argument inside a function is not a good idea because it leads to unexpected results and more difficult maintenance

Comment: Actually, good catch, it was mutating the original. I have since updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter, after accessing each other object first with .forEach()

```js
const foo = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: [ {id: 1, a: null}, {id: 2, a: 224}, {id: 3, a: 345}, ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bar: [ {id: 4, a: 763}, {id: 5, a: null}, {id: 3, a: 111}, ]
  }
]

foo.forEach(obj => obj.bar = obj.bar.filter(subObj => subObj.a != null))

console.log(foo)
```

If you did not want to mutate the array, you could use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` to clone it:

```js
var foo = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: [ {id: 1, a: null}, {id: 2, a: 224}, {id: 3, a: 345}, ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bar: [ {id: 4, a: 763}, {id: 5, a: null}, {id: 3, a: 111}, ]
  }
]
var newFoo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo))
newFoo.forEach(obj => obj.bar = obj.bar.filter(subObj => subObj.a != null))

console.log('Original:\n', foo)
console.log('New Array:\n', newFoo)
```

Comment: Haha, oh well, not much you can do. You get those who just want their answer to be at the top :p Like you said they don't even say why they downvoted, If they did, I could rewrite my answer, which would benefit the person and the community.

Comment: @AminJafari I didn't downvote but explaining the downvote is never a good idea. It leads to comment wars and revenge downvoting

Comment: @adiga not explaining the downvote is discouraging to the person answering and may lead not to answering any more questions and not to put any effort in SO in general. Plus some people use the voting system more like a "like/dislike" button, even though the answer is right just like this case

Comment: @adiga I agree with you both, but I couldn't care less about rep. If someone doesn't like my answer, so be it, but if it's wrong, telling me why it's wrong helps me and the community learn.

Answer (score 0):

The outer method should be `map()` instead of `filter()`.

```js
const foo = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: [ {id: 1, a: null}, {id: 2, a: 224}, {id: 3, a: 345}, ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bar: [ {id: 4, a: 763}, {id: 5, a: null}, {id: 3, a: 111}, ]
  }
]

const res = foo.map(elem => ({...elem,bar:elem.bar.filter(bar => bar.a !== null)}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: This is what I'd do! Nice and clean

Comment: I would but I'm not the OP :)